# Why can't I create an advanced routing manager?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm working with the nokia here api and I'm trying to create an advanced routing manager in javascript which for some reason does not work. Clearly I'm missing something but I just can't find it.

Basically that's all I'm doing:

```
<head>
    <title>isoscope</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://js.cit.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        nokia.Settings.set("appId", "xxxx");
        nokia.Settings.set("authenticationToken", "xxxx");  
        var routingManager = new nokia.maps.advrouting.Manager();
    </script>
</head>
```

And all I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Manager' of undefined
```

It could have something to do with the Enterprise API vs the regular API because creating instances of e.g. a map works fine. But since I have access to the Enterprise API this shouldn't be any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok for reasons of closure and completeness here's my solution to my problem as a regular answer.
Obviously the script I was including (I copied the URL from the isoline example on [this page](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/enterprise-api-explorer) was just the wrong one. The correct one (or at least the one that works for me) can be found [here](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/enterprise-maps).

It's

```
http://js.api.here.com/ee/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all
```